# How to return double string in models django

Tags: python, django

Helo everyone. I have a little problem. I've create a models:

```
class Cudzoziemiec(models.Model):
    imie = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name="Imię", unique=False)
    nazwisko = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Nazwisko", unique=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Cudzoziemca'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Cudzoziemcy'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nazwisko

class Umowa(models.Model):
    RODZAJ_UMOWY = (
        ('UP', 'Umowa o pracę'),
        ('UZ', 'Umowa zlecenie'),
        ('UD', 'Umowa o dzieło'),
        )
    osoba = models.ForeignKey(Cudzoziemiec, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Wybierz cudzoziemca")
    umowa_rodzaj = models.CharField(max_length=250,choices=RODZAJ_UMOWY, verbose_name="Rodzaj umowy")
    nr_umowy = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    umowa_od = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name="Data rozpoczęcia pracy")
    umowa_do = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name="Data zakończenia pracy")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Umowę'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Umowy'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nr_umowy
```

In panel admin everything works ok. But how to display "imie"+"nazwisko" in panel admin in case when I want to create a new record in Umowy.  Now I have only "nazwisko" if I want to add new record via Umowa class, selected a "osoba" in that class.

EDIT:
When I want to add new record the django return me a error:

```
__str__ returned non-string (type int)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that's what you want, but usually the string representation used in the select input generated by Django forms use the `__str__` method:

```
class Cudzoziemiec(models.Model):
    imie = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name="Imię", unique=False)
    nazwisko = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Nazwisko", unique=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Cudzoziemca'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Cudzoziemcy'

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.imie , self.nazwisko)
```

Or equivalent result:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.imie , self.nazwisko)
```

Or if you are using Python 3.6+

```
def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.imie} {self.nazwisko}'
```

---

About the "non-string" error, it's because `__str__` should return a string object. In your second case, you are returning a `self.nr_umowy`, which is a `PositiveIntegerField`.

You have to cast it:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.nr_umowy)
```

Comment: Yes Viktor is working. I took first solution and everything is ok. Thank You.

Comment: Viktor could You check my edit? The django return me a error when I want to save a record